# Subset and plot data by for loop / lappy

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have about 300 sites located over multiple mountains types. I am trying to produce some meaningful plots. Therefore, I would like to subset my data by mountain type (type), and plot it by ggplot2. I would like to automate the process by for loop or by lapply, but I am beginner in both.

I have found some good examples using for loop : http://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/resources/R/loops_with_ggplot2.html
or using lapply: [Use for loop in ggplot2 to generate a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36813238/use-for-loop-in-ggplot2-to-generate-a-list)

However, both approaches generate empty plots. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix my code?

```
# Create dummy data
df<- data.frame(loc = rep(c("l1", "l2"), each = 3),
                name = rep(c("A", "B"), 3),
                grid = c(5,6,7,2,3,5),
                area = c(5,10,1,1,3,1),
                areaOrig = rep(c(20, 10, 5), each = 2))

df2<-rbind(df, df)

# Create two mountain types types
df2$type = rep(c("y", "z"), each = 6)
```

**Create `function` to produce plots:**

```
require(ggplot2)

type.graph <- function(df2, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {

  # Create list of locations
  type_list <-unique(df2$type)

  # Create a for loop to produce ggpot plots
  for (i in seq_along(type_list)) {

    # create a plot for each loc in df
    plot<-

      windows()

      ggplot(subset(df2, df2$type == type_list[i]),
             aes(x = grid, 
                 y = area)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        ggtitle(type_list[i]) +
        facet_grid(loc ~name)

    print(plot)
  }
}

type.graph(df2)
```

**Use `lapply` to produce plots:**

```
#significant SNPs
type_list <- unique(df2$type)

#create list of ggplots per type
p_re <-
  lapply(type_list, function(i){

    ggplot(subset(df2, type == type_list[i]), 
           aes(x = grid, 
               y = area)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")

  })

#assign names
names(p_re) <- type_list

#plot
p_re$y
```

Comment: One of your problems comes from the `plot <- windows()` command (it spans multiple lines in your code, but this is what it executes).  So, your code opens a new window, stores the result (`NULL`) as `plot`, creates a ggplot object but doesn't save it, then prints `plot` (again, `NULL`).  If you change it to be `plot <- ggplot(...`, it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest using a the purrr package as part of the tidyverse, nesting the data frame by the grouping factor, then looping through the subset data. Below is an example:

```
library(tidyverse)

by_type <- df2 %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(plot = map(data, 
                    ~ggplot(. ,aes(x = grid, y = area)) +
                      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
                      ggtitle(.) +
                      facet_grid(loc ~name)))

by_type
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  type  data             plot    
  <chr> <list>           <list>  
1 y     <tibble [6 × 5]> <S3: gg>
2 z     <tibble [6 × 5]> <S3: gg>
```

The above gives you a normal data frame, but the data and plot columns are list columns. So the first "cell" for data contains all the data for `type == y` and the second contains all the data for `type == z`. This basic structure is created by `tidyr::nest`. You then create a new variable, which I've called plot, by looping through the data list column with `purrr::map`, and you just need to substitute the data argument for `.`. Note there are `map2` and `pmap` functions for when you want to loop through more than one thing at a time (for example, if you wanted your title to be something different.

You can then easily look at your data with `by_type$plot`, or save them with

```
walk2(by_type$type, by_type$plot, 
      ~ggsave(paste0(.x, ".pdf"), .y))
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, that's an interesting approach! I will certainly remember ! And I appreciate a lot the way how to store my plots.. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
require(ggplot2)

type.graph <- function(df2, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {

  # Create list of locations
  type_list <-unique(df2$type)

  # Create a for loop to produce ggpot plots
  for (i in seq_along(type_list)) {

    # create a plot for each loc in df
    plot<-
        ggplot(subset(df2, df2$type == type_list[i]),
             aes(x = grid, 
                 y = area)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        ggtitle(type_list[i]) +
        facet_grid(loc ~name)
    windows()
    print(plot)
  }
}

type.graph(df2)
```

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago, before tidyverse, I had used ggplot2 to produce list of plot objects using similar way you do. **At the end of custom function I used to put explicit `return()` statement to return created object.** That worked for me (for example, to run `ggsave()` later).

Example with custom histogram with `df` as main dataset to plot followed by some extra parameters:

```
ggHistFunc <- function (cl, df, ymax, st) {
    mn <- st$means[st$variable==cl]
    P50 <- st$medians[st$variable==cl]
    P10 <- st$P10[st$variable==cl]
    P90 <- st$P90[st$variable==cl]
    gghist <-
        ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = cl)) +
        geom_histogram(binwidth = diff(range(df[,cl]))/10, aes(y = ..count..),
                       fill = "white", colour = "black") +
        geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(mn, mn)), y = c(0, ymax),
                  aes(x=x), colour="green", size=1) +
        geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(P50, P50)), y = c(0, ymax),
                  aes(x=x), colour="brown", size=1) +
        geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(P10, P10)), y = c(0, ymax),
                  aes(x=x), colour="blue", size=1) +
        geom_line(data = data.frame(x = c(P90, P90)), y = c(0, ymax),
                  aes(x=x), colour="red", size=1)
    #print(gghist)
    return(gghist)
}
```

And followed by "loop" to create histogram for all parameters:

```
gg_Hist_HM <- lapply(X = as.list(names(params_HM)),
                     FUN = ggHistFunc, df = params_HM, ymax = 100, st = stat_HM)
```

**Now I see the approach proposed above with purrr package looks more elegant!**