# Formatting R console output

Tags: r, console, formatting, tags

I would like to be able to copy and paste the output in R console without always having to remove these tags and quotes

```
print('love')
[1] "love"
```

**What I require**

```
print('love')
love
```

**Note:** I also want to remove the `[1]` not only the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `cat` function, it will indeed print your string without parenthesis:

```
cat('love')
#### love
```

See the help page `?cat`

> Outputs the objects, concatenating the representations. cat performs
>   much less conversion than print.

You might also use `print` with the quote argument:

```
print("love", quote=FALSE)
#### [1] love
```

That way, you still get the `[1]`
See also this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5218361/3871924

Comment: @TSR this should work: cat(noquote("love"))