# Convert character to variable names used in formula in R

Tags: r

I am beginner of R, I met a problem which might be simple for you. Thanks in advance if could give me some help. I am not sure whether the title does reflect the problem I want to ask. To make my problem clear, I will use a simple example.

Let's say we have data frame containing two factors (FE and DI) and three variables (SR1, SR2 and SR3) like:

```
df<-data.frame(FE=rep(c("FL","FM","FH"),4),DI=rep(c("DL","DH"),each=6),
SR1=rpois(12,10),SR2=rpois(12,15),SR3=rpois(12,20))
```

I know how to calculate the means of variables according to the factors by using "aggregate", for example:

```
df.me1<-aggregate(SR1~FE,df,mean)
df.me2<-aggregate(cbind(SR1,SR2,SR3)~FE+DI,df,mean)
```

Then, I make two characters (vars and facs) consisting of names of the three variables and the two factors:

```
vars<-c("SR1","SR2","SR3")
facs<-c("FE","DI")
```

Now, I want to do the calculations in the following formula for some reason

```
df.me1<-aggregate(vars[1]~facs[1],df,mean)
df.me2<-aggregate(cbind(vars[1],vars[2],vars[3])~facs[1]+facs[2],df,mean)
```

The codes certainly do not work, so what should I do to make them work in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more generic solution for dealing with strings in equations I like using the functionality eval(parse(text = "A string to execute")) for example in your code

```
eval(parse(text = paste("df.me1<-aggregate(",vars[1],"~",facs[1],",df,mean)",sep="")))
```

and I get the following result

```
> df.me1
  FE   SR1
1 FH  9.75
2 FL 10.75
3 FM 10.25
```

I also find that functionality useful when retrieving information in a list that is referenced by a string.

here is the paste command

```
> paste("df.me1<-aggregate(",vars[1],"~",facs[1],",df,mean)",sep="")
[1] "df.me1<-aggregate(SR1~FE,df,mean)"
```

For the second part

```
eval(parse(text = paste("df.me2<-aggregate(cbind(",vars[1],",",vars[2],",",vars[3],")~",facs[1],"+",facs[2],",df,mean)",sep="")))
```

Comment: Great, I like your answer best. I can see that "eval(parse(text = "A string to execute"))" is a more general solution and really solves my problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do this. One would be through `aggregate`'s formula interface, which is what you're currently trying to do. In order to make this work, you'd have to create a string that includes your dependent and independent variables. Then you'd convert that string to a formula object using `as.formula()`. This is overcomplicated, since it requires a lot of witchcraft with `sprintf` and/or `paste`.

A simpler way to do this would be through `aggregate`'s `by` argument, which is a little more friendly for substitutions made through variable names.

```
df.me1 <- aggregate(df[vars[1]], by = df[facs[1]], FUN = mean)

  FE   SR1
1 FH 10.00
2 FL 10.00
3 FM  9.25

df.me2 <- aggregate(df[vars], by = df[facs], FUN = mean)

  FE DI  SR1  SR2  SR3
1 FH DH  9.0 11.5 22.5
2 FL DH  8.0 16.5 21.5
3 FM DH 10.0 14.5 21.0
4 FH DL 11.0 16.5 18.0
5 FL DL 12.0 18.0 15.0
6 FM DL  8.5 13.0 24.0
```

Comment: Your solution works for the "aggregate" function example here, however, it doesn't solve my problem how to convert character to variable names used in a formula. Therefore, I prefer the answers using "eval(parse(text = "A string to execute"))" or "get()" which are more general solutions for my problem. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

@jdobres' answer is cleaner and probably better in most instances, but if you must do this exactly as you've written it, then referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215481/remove-quotes-from-a-character-vector-in-r) answer, you can just use `get()`.

```
df.me2<-aggregate(cbind(SR1,SR2,SR3)~FE+DI,df,mean)
df.me2.get<-aggregate(cbind(get(vars[1]),get(vars[2]),get(vars[3]))~get(facs[1])+get(facs[2]),df,mean)
```

And checking if they are the same:

```
df.me2 == df.me2.get

       FE   DI  SR1  SR2  SR3
[1,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[2,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[3,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[4,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[5,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[6,] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Cool. That is the answer I am looking for, thanks so much!