# Resolving a variable value within a function call R

Tags: r

I have a data frame defined as follows:

```
model_comp
         logLik       IC  Lack of fit  Res var
W2.4  -353.2939 716.5878 1.361885e-01 26.80232
baro5 -353.2936 718.5871          NaN 27.04363
LL.5  -353.2940 718.5880          NaN 27.04384
LL.3  -360.3435 728.6871 3.854799e-04 29.99842
W1.3  -360.3842 728.7684 3.707592e-04 30.01948
W1.4  -360.3129 730.6258 7.850947e-05 30.25028
LL.4  -360.3170 730.6340 7.818416e-05 30.25243
```

The best model fit is the one with the lowest IC (information criteria). I want to use the best fit to do some plotting etc...  So I created:

```
> bestmodel <- noquote(paste0(as.name(rownames(model_comp[which.min(model_comp$IC),])),"()"))
> bestmodel
[1] W2.4()
```

I want to use the W2.4() as a function call to a the DRC package.

For example this call works when manually specified:

```
drm(y~x,logDose = 10, fct=W2.4())
```

I'm trying to use the value in `bestmodel` instead to do something like:

```
drm(y~x,logDose = 10,fct = as.formula(paste(bestmodel)))
```

I've tried all the options given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215481/remove-quotes-from-a-character-vector-in-r) with no success.  I've messed with as.formula(), noquote(), as.name() with no success.

I also tried `as.name(paste0(as.name(bestmodel),"()"))` where I didn't add on the "()" in the bestmodel definition above. Still no dice.

```
model_comp <- structure(list(logLik = c(-353.293902612472, -353.293568997018, 
-353.294024776211, -360.343530770823, -360.384220907907, -360.312897918459, 
-360.317018443052), IC = c(716.587805224944, 718.587137994035, 
718.588049552421, 728.687061541646, 728.768441815814, 730.625795836919, 
730.634036886105), `Lack of fit` = c(0.136188459104035, NaN, 
NaN, 0.000385479884900107, 0.000370759187117765, 7.85094742623572e-05, 
7.81841606352332e-05), `Res var` = c(26.8023196097934, 27.0436263934882, 
27.0438389102235, 29.9984226526044, 30.0194755526501, 30.2502847248304, 
30.2524338881051)), .Names = c("logLik", "IC", "Lack of fit", 
"Res var"), row.names = c("W2.4", "baro5", "LL.5", "LL.3", "W1.3", 
"W1.4", "LL.4"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: you should probably save both the models as well as the performance measures in one object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using `noquote()` not to draw the quotes around a string doesn't turn a character value into an executable piece of code. There is a big different in R between a character value an a symbol or function call. You can't really just replace one with the other.

So let's say you have extracted the character value from the rownames

```
x <- "W2.4"
```

This is basically the string version of the function you want. You can get the value of a symbol (in this case the function `W2.4` from the drc:package) from its string name with `get()`. So you can call

```
drm(y~x, logDose = 10, fct = get(x)())
```

Note the extra parenthesis. The `get(x)`-call returns the `W2.4` function, and the second set of parenthesis calls that function returned by `get()`.

Using the `ryegrass` dataset that comes with the `drc` package, we can see that these two lines return the same thing

```
drm(rootl ~ conc, data = ryegrass, fct = W2.4())
drm(rootl ~ conc, data = ryegrass, fct = get(x)())
```

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick

Comment: You could also use `match.fun(x)` rather than `get`