# How to perform logical operators through indexing in data.table at R?

Tags: r, indexing, key, data.table, logical-operators

I am trying to figure out how I can perform `logical operators` when I use **indexing** in `data.table package` in `R`?

Following is the example. I make a `datatable` named as `dt`. and then make the `var2` as the key in my `datatable`:

```
> dt = data.table(var1 = rep(LETTERS[1:5],2), var2 = seq(1,20, 2), var3 = ceiling(rnorm(10, 3, 2)))
> dt
    var1 var2 var3
 1:    A    1    5
 2:    B    3    3
 3:    C    5    0
 4:    D    7    6
 5:    E    9    3
 6:    A   11    4
 7:    B   13    2
 8:    C   15    1
 9:    D   17    3
10:    E   19    7

> setkey(dt, var2)
```

So now I want to identify all the values in my already defined `key (var2)` which are `less than 10 ( <10)`. Doing the following tries give me `errors`.

```
> dt[ < 10]
Error: unexpected '<' in "dt[ <"
> dt[ .< 10]
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '.' not found
> dt[ .(< 10)]
```

**my expectation would be :**

```
     var1 var2 var3

 1:    A   11    4
 2:    B   13    2
 3:    C   15    1
 4:    D   17    3
 5:    E   19    7
```

BTW, I know that just by doing `dt[var2 <10]` I will get the result. BUT please consider that I want to get the concept of Indexing in `data.table` and understand and know how to do it without calling the `key(var2)` in every each of my command!

Any help with explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: `dt[var2 < 10]`? With the explanation being that you need to specify *something* to be less than 10?

Comment: @Gregor, I know this and it is very obvious!  But the concept of indexing is that I DO NOT need to call the column name (key) every time. so , how I can do it without calling `var2` in my command?

Comment: From `?setkey` or `?key` it looks like you can call `key()` on a table to get the key, so `dt[dt[[key(dt)]] < 10]` works for that. You also might want to edit the question to make it state that you want to do it programmatically without calling `var2` in your command.

Comment: @Gregor thank you for the information.  Although ur answer is giving the correct output but  since the concept of `indexing` in `data.table` is to avoid writing LONG command, I am expecting there should be another way much easier to address it.

Comment: The short way is `dt[var2 < 10]`, but you say you don't want the short way. You have several complicating factors: you want to reference the `key` column programmatically and you assume there is a single `key` column. I wish you luck in finding a shorter way, but it seems foolish to care so much about a 9-keystroke difference--less if the name of your key column is longer.

Comment: I'm afraid `dt[J()]` currently doesn't work for *non-equi* joins, so you can either specify the range you want to join with `dt[J(0:9), nomatch = 0L]` or do something like `dt[get(key(dt)) < 10]` or `dt[eval(as.name(key(dt))) < 10]` or what Gregor suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?setkey`, `key(dt)` get the key columns in a character vector. Assuming your table has a single key column, then you can get what you want with:

```
dt[dt[[key(dt)]] < 10]
```

Thanks to David Arenburg, you can also use `get()`:

```
dt[get(key(dt)) < 10]
```

This is a little bit shorter and probably the way to go.

The other way I can think to do it is much worse:

```
dt[eval(parse(text = paste(key(dt), "< 10")))]
```

Comment: Also `dt[get(key(dt)) < 10]` and `dt[eval(as.name(key(dt))) < 10]`

Answer (score 1):

from documentation https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4/topics/setkey

Here is a key to the solution , if possible

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.10.4
  The fastest way to learn (by data.table authors): https://www.datacamp.com/courses/data-analysis-the-data-table-way
  Documentation: ?data.table, example(data.table) and browseVignettes("data.table")
  Release notes, videos and slides: http://r-datatable.com
> data(mtcars)
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

> mtcars=data.table(mtcars)
> setkey(mtcars,mpg)
> key(mtcars)
[1] "mpg"


> mtcars[mpg<15,,]
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
2: 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
3: 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
4: 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
5: 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
> mtcars["mpg"<15,,]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 11 cols: mpg,cyl,disp,hp,drat,wt...
```

The problem lies that key(DT) is giving "var2" while the subset in a datatable demands var2 (without the quotes) - we get this using `get`

So now using [Remove quotes from a character vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215481/remove-quotes-from-a-character-vector-in-r)

This is the simplest way

```
#get(key(mtcars))

    > mtcars[get(key(mtcars))<15]
    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
2: 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
3: 13.3   8  350 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
4: 14.3   8  360 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
5: 14.7   8  440 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
```

For your datatable it will be

```
DT[get(key(DT))<10]
```

which is the same as @DavidArenburg 's  simple and elegant answer

Comment: I am afraid not!

Comment: Did you even test your answer?

Comment: I cant test my answer. I am in office and unable to use R

Comment: see the link. basically you need a parameter to select data. did you try it. can you paste error. what else have you tried