# for loop in R using a list of strings as variables - with and without quotes

Tags: r, string, loops, quotes

I would like to create a loop that would run over a list of strings. This list of strings contains name of the variables that need to be plugged-in the syntax. My syntax sometimes need them with quotes (and then it works) and sometimes without quotes (and then it fails). I have tried solutions from here [Remove quotes from a character vector in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215481/remove-quotes-from-a-character-vector-in-r) but it didn't work.

here is an example of what I try to do:

```
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)
list=c("mpg", "cyl")
for (i in list) {
  print(i)
  df=mtcars[,c(i, "gear")] #this works
  df1 = group_by(df, gear) %>% summarize(Y=sum(i)) # this doesn't work - it doesn't recognize i as variable name
}
```

I'd appreciate your help

Regards,
Polina

Comment: It's generally bad practice to name variables after oft-used base R functions. While not a syntax error (and R usually knows what you intend), I recommend against using `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping `i` in a `get`.

```
for (i in list) {
  print(i)
  df=mtcars[,c(i, "gear")] #this works
  df1 = group_by(df, gear) %>% summarize(Y=sum(get(i))) # this doesn't work - it doesn't recognize i as variable name
}
```

It's also worth reading about `sym` and `!!` etc

Comment: As @RuiBarradas points out below, this overwrites the `df1` data frame on each iteration of the loop, which is unlikely to be OP's intent.

Answer (score 0):

To correct the error of accessing the variable given by a character variable, use `!!rlang::sym(i)`.

```
for (i in list) {
  print(i)
  df=mtcars[,c(i, "gear")] #this works
  df1 = group_by(df, gear) %>% summarize(Y = sum(!!rlang::sym(i)))
}
```

But there is another error in the question's code, the output `df1` is rewritten every time through the loop.
Here is a corrected loop.

```
df_list <- lapply(list, function(i){
  print(i)
  df <- mtcars[,c(i, "gear")] #this works
  group_by(df, gear) %>% summarize(Y = sum(!!rlang::sym(i)))
})

df_list[[1]]
## A tibble: 3 x 2
#   gear     Y
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     3  242.
#2     4  294.
#3     5  107.
```

Comment: Also note the [`.data` pronoun](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/tidyeval-data.html), which can be useful when working with strings and tidy evaluation. E.g., `sum(.data[[i]])`

Comment: @aosmith You could post your comment as an answer, imho that's precisely what the question asks for, what to put in `sum` when the summand is given as a character variable.